# How to get the token from api in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, jwt

I am using react native and I want to get the access token and the id from api which is created in nodejs using JWT authentication and axios.

Any suggestion please

here is my code below:

**Services:**

```
const updatePasswordEmailLink = (id, token, password, passwordConfirm) => {

  return (
    http.post(`/reset-password/${id}/${token}`, JSON.stringify({ ...{ password, passwordConfirm } }))
  )
}
```

**ResetScreen:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    //how can I get the id and the token

  }, [])

  const resetPasswordEmail = async () => {


    AuthService.updatePasswordEmailLink(id, token, password, passwordConfirm).then(
      () => {
  
        navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
        return true;
      })
      .catch((error) => {

        Alert.alert('Error!', error.message);
        return false;
      })



  }
```

Comment: First you need to show what your api returns

Comment: I should get the id & token first to run the code

Comment: If it is dynamically generated token then api should provide a different route to generate and return the token, this can then be called in your useEffect. If it is one time token then that should be saved on a config file and import it from there and use it on your api call.

Comment: So for example, a login route can generate a valid token when the correct username and password is supplied. Then you store that token in a state or persistent state and use it when reseting password. Hope that makes sense.